Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr>warning while using Accordion inside tbody
I am using Accordian from react-bootstrap, I want that the table row can be expanded to view another table, it is working fine but giving me warnings on browser console.
<div className="row me-2 ms-2">
                <table className="table accordian-table table header-fixed border mt-2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="30%" className="text-center">Col 1</th>
                            <th width="30%" className="text-center">Col 2</th>
                            <th width="30%" className="text-center">Col 3</th>
                            <th width="25px" className="float end"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="scroll">
                        <Accordion activeKey={activeAccordionKey}
                            onSelect={(selectedKey) => setActiveAccordionKey(selectedKey)} flush>
                            {
                                (items?.length) ?
                                    [...items].map((item, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <tr key={index} onClick={() => getFlows(item)}>
                                                <Accordion.Item eventKey={index}>
                                                    <Accordion.Header className="main-table-content">
                                                        <td width="30%" title={item.prop1} className="text-center pt-2">
                                                            {item.prop1}
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="30%" title={item.prop2} className="text-center pt-2">
                                                            {item.onboardingInfo.prop2}
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="30%" title={item.prop3} className="text-center pt-2">
                                                            {item.onboardingInfo.prop3}
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="25px">{" "}</td>
                                                    </Accordion.Header>
                                                    <Accordion.Body>
                                                        <table className="table" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th>Flow Name</th>
                                                                    <th>Flow Type</th>
                                                                    <th>Dnid</th>
                                                                    <th>Ext</th>
                                                                    <th>Created By</th>
                                                                    <th>Created On</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                {
                                                                    (selectedItem?.length) ?
                                                                        [...selectedItem.values()].map((slItem) => {
                                                                            return (
                                                                                <tr key={slItem.flowName}>
                                                                                    <td>{slItem.flowName}</td>
                                                                                    <td>{slItem.flowTypeId}</td>
                                                                                    <td>{slItem.dnid}</td>                                                                                        
                                                                                    <td>{slItem.createdBy}</td>
                                                                                    <td>{slItem.createdOn}</td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            )
                                                                        })
                                                                        : <tr><td>No Configs Available</td></tr>
                                                                }
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </Accordion.Body>
                                                </Accordion.Item >
                                            </tr>
                                        )
                                    }) : <tr><td>No ItemsFound</td></tr>
                            }
                        </Accordion>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

It gives me following warning in browser console:
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of .
Can someone please help me removing this, or any other alternative?

If you look at the source code for react-bootstrap you'll see that the Accordion code has a lot of div elements. The browser is complaining that a div element inside a table row element is not valid HTML. So, unless you remove the accordion from the table you can't get rid of the warning.

The correct structure of an HTML table is:
<table>
  <tbody> // optional
    <tr> // row
      <td>anything can be here</td>
      <td>another cell</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>

So a tr (row) can only contain td (data) elements.

It seems like you're placing < td > elements directly within an <Accordion.Header>, which is likely causing the warnings.
Instead of placing < td > elements directly within the <Accordion.Header>, you should wrap them within a < tr > ` like this


<Accordion.Header className="main-table-content">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" title={item.prop1} className="text-center pt-2">
            {item.prop1}
        </td>
        <td width="30%" title={item.prop2} className="text-center pt-2">
            {item.onboardingInfo.prop2}
        </td>
        <td width="30%" title={item.prop3} className="text-center pt-2">
            {item.onboardingInfo.prop3}
        </td>
        <td width="25px">{" "}</td>
    </tr>
</Accordion.Header>



`
this may help you
